# How to set up the view content trigger for the Facebook pixel so that it only fires on the landing page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-manager

I was wondering how you can trigger the view content event dynamically.

We have different pages on our website and sometimes the ads we run on Facebook land on a product page, on the home page, on a category page, etc.

What is the best way to make my View Content trigger only ONCE (just on the landing page) when the customer clicks the ad on Facebook to come to our site?

Comment: When you say that ads "redirect," what does that mean?   You usually place ads on a page and when users click the ads there are no redirects to other pages on your site involved.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. With redirect I simply mean Customer clicks ad -> Customer goes to the page where the ad leads to.

Comment: I edited your question based on that comment, but it still doesn't make much sense to me.   Why are you triggering a view content trigger when a user clicks an ad?   Why would you have problems with this trigger firing more than once?

Comment: I want to track how many people clicked my ad and then viewed the content connected to that ad. 

If a customer then goes to other pages, doesn't this add more view contents then to my pixel? 

What I would like to achieve:

Customer clicks ad -> Sees product -> +1 view content.

What I think would happen:

Customer clicks ad -> Sees product -> +1 view content -> Goes to list view-> +1 view content -> Clicks new product -> +1 view content

Comment: I think I understand now.  I'll edit again.